# How to change a div in text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div which looks like a message bubble. on Edit I want to switch it to text area with save button. Below is my effort with HTML and CSS. Can someone please help?

```js
function divClicked() {
  var divHtml = $(this).prev('div').html();
  var editableText = $("<textarea />");
  editableText.val(divHtml);
  $(this).prev('div').replaceWith(editableText);
  editableText.focus();
  // setup the blur event for this new textarea
  editableText.blur(editableTextBlurred);
}

function editableTextBlurred() {
  var html = $(this).val();
  var viewableText = $("<div>");
  viewableText.html(html);
  $(this).replaceWith(viewableText);
  // setup the click event for this new div
  viewableText.click(divClicked);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".edit-message").click(divClicked);
});
```

```css
.comment-block {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #b4bbc6;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-comment {
  color: #acb4c2;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.comment-author {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}

.comment-date {
  color: #90949c;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment-text {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="comment-block edit-message">
  <div class="bottom-comment">
    <div class="comment-author">Guestname</div>
    <div class="comment-date">Aug 24, 2014 at 23:35</div>
  </div>
  <p class="comment-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto temporibus iste nostrum dolorem natus recusandae incidunt voluptatum. Eligendi voluptatum ducimus architecto tempore, quaerat explicabo veniam fuga corporis totam reprehenderit quasi sapiente
    modi tempora at perspiciatis mollitia, dolores voluptate. Cumque, corrupti?
    <a href="#">Edit your message</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You would need to swap out a child of a container placeholder such as a div to do that  with JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp

Comment: I forgot to add JS @Taplar. Let me edit.

Comment: Are you sure you want to switch from the DIV to a Textarea? Why not just use `contenteditable`?

Comment: @ControlAltDel I just want to give my user an option to edit back the message if anything is incorrect. What could be more suitable?

Comment: Why couldn't you "edit back" in a contenteditable DIV?

Comment: The user is coming from another page to here, and we are bringing to confirm order here. If the user has no issues, he can click on confirm the order, or we let him edit his comments again. So edit and get the textarea field is just an incase.

Comment: Here's a tutorial: https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: For future reference, rather than including a link to a jsfiddle, click the `<>` button in the question options, or hit Ctrl+M, to bring up the onsite editor and make a runnable snippet on site.  Don't make people trying to help you go to a third party site to see your code.

Comment: Thanks for this @ControlAltDel. Can this contenteditable be enabled on "edit your message" link only?

Comment: @Taplar It gives this error always: http://prntscr.com/moc4rr

Comment: I don't see that at all by running the snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with some JS.

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```js
edit = () => {
  let commentText = document.querySelector('.comment-text');

  let textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
  // Set the content of the textarea to the content of the `.comment-text` box
  textArea.innerHTML = commentText.innerHTML;
  // Added a class so you may do some styling in CSS
  textArea.setAttribute('class', 'comment-textarea');
  commentText.parentNode.replaceChild(textArea, commentText);
}
```

```css
.comment-block {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #b4bbc6;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-comment {
  color: #acb4c2;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.comment-author {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}

.comment-date {
  color: #90949c;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment-text {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 20px;
}


/* You could style your text area how you would like here */

.comment-textarea {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-block">
  <div class="bottom-comment">
    <div class="comment-author">Guestname</div>
    <div class="comment-date">Aug 24, 2014 at 23:35</div>
  </div>
  <p class="comment-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto temporibus iste nostrum dolorem natus recusandae incidunt voluptatum. Eligendi voluptatum ducimus architecto tempore, quaerat explicabo veniam fuga corporis totam reprehenderit quasi sapiente
    modi tempora at perspiciatis mollitia, dolores voluptate. Cumque, corrupti?
    <a href="#" onclick="edit()">Edit your message</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Also, if you would like to toggle it, you may do it like this:

```js
edit = () => {
  let commentText = document.querySelector('.comment-text');
  let replacement;
  if (commentText.classList.contains('active')) {
    replacement = document.createElement('p');
    replacement.setAttribute('class', 'comment-text');
  } else {
    replacement = document.createElement('textarea');
    replacement.setAttribute('class', 'comment-text active');
  }
  replacement.innerHTML = commentText.innerHTML;
  commentText.parentNode.replaceChild(replacement, commentText);
}
```

```css
.comment-block {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0, .7);
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #b4bbc6;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bottom-comment {
  color: #acb4c2;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.comment-author {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: black;
}

.comment-date {
  color: #90949c;
  font-size: 11px;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.comment-text {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  line-height: 20px;
}

/* You could style your text area how you would like here */

.active {
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment-block">
  <div class="bottom-comment">
    <div class="comment-author">Guestname</div>
    <div class="comment-date">Aug 24, 2014 at 23:35</div>
  </div>
  <p class="comment-text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto temporibus iste nostrum dolorem natus recusandae incidunt voluptatum. Eligendi voluptatum ducimus architecto tempore, quaerat explicabo veniam fuga corporis totam reprehenderit quasi sapiente
    modi tempora at perspiciatis mollitia, dolores voluptate. Cumque, corrupti?
  </p>
  <a href="#" onclick="edit()">Edit your message</a>
</div>
```

*Edit: It may be of interest to you to get and set the height.*

One way to do that:

```
let height = commentText.offsetHeight;
...
replacement.style.height = `${height}px`;
```

Hope this helps,